# Unable to convert varchar to datetime in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, datetime-format

In my MySql table there's a column called _time of type varchar. The values it holds are in the format: `year month day hour minute` without the whitespaces: `201409201945` I want to convert it to `datetime` so I'm doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE COLUMN `_time` `date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

And it throws this error for some reason:

`Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '201409201945' for column '_date_time' at row 1    0.036 sec`

Comment: I'd add a new column with the correct type, run an update to do the  appropriate data conversion, and then drop the old column

Comment: @Arkain, is the format of the date correct?

Comment: @Arkain how will user do update using existing data. (Old format data)

Comment: @Prashant, in no way.

Comment: With the help of the function [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp you can cast it to date time, you just need to  add 00 after to make it valid. `CAST(CONCAT(_time, '00') AS DATETIME);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three steps @Arkain mentioned would be with the help of the function [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
-- add the new column
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `date_time` DATETIME; 

-- update the new column with the help of the function STR_TO_DATE
UPDATE `my_table` SET `date_time` = STR_TO_DATE(`_time`, '%Y%m%d%H%i');

-- drop the old column
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP COLUMN `_time`;
```

The complete list of specifiers for STR_TO_DATE can be found at [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), here an excerpt with those I used:

```
%d  Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%H  Hour (00..23)
%i  Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%m  Month, numeric (00..12)
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
```

[Demo of the UPDATE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6694/1)

If the new column should have the attribute NOT NOLL, one way could be to set the sql mode before the operation to '' and reset the sql_mode later on:

```
SET @old_mode = @@sql_mode;
SET @@sql_mode = '';        -- permits zero values in DATETIME columns

ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL; 
UPDATE `my_table` SET `date_time` = STR_TO_DATE(`_time`, '%Y%m%d%H%i');
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP COLUMN `_time`;

SET @@sql_mode = @old_mode;
```

[Updated Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1be5d/1)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Very true, fixed that thoughtless copy and paste error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried and it and I got no error. The value of the new column for existing rows defaults to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: are you sure it has "i" in the '%Y%m%d%H%i'?

Comment: @abl: That could be a matter of the sql_mode of MySQL.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Yes, see the list of specifiers for STR_TO_DATE, listed at [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: all _date_time are NULL

Comment: The format string was build by your specifications and the example you gave. See it working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6694/1)

Comment: @VMai is there a sql_mode that does not allow adding the column as `NOT NULL`? I only managed to get an error when using mode `NO_ZERO_DATE`, but I think the actual cause of the error in this case is not that the column does not have a default value, but that the (implicit) default value is not a valid date.

Comment: That was my typo. How about NOT NULL? If the first command one can add NOT NULL and set DEFAULT to "" or something, can't we? Or what else can one do? Because ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY `date_time` datetime NOT NULL; doesn't look that good because one has to specify datetime again.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Do you need NOT NULL? To get an automatic initialization you could use since MySQL 5.6.x `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @Alexander Supertramp: You could set the sql_mode before the operation to a value that permits zero dates, create your column NOT NULL, perform the update, drop the old table and reset the sql_mode;

Answer (score 2):

If your `varchar` data were formatted like this  '2014-09-20 19:45'  altering your column's data type would work. Why? that's the character representation used by `DATETIME` and other time-oriented data types.

But it isn't. So, what choices do you have?
One is to use these four steps:

1. alter the table to add a new `DATETIME` column with a temporary name
2. do an `UPDATE` with no `WHERE` clause to fill in the values of that column
3. alter the table to drop the previous column
4. alter the table to rename your new column to have the same name as the column you just dropped.

Here's how that would go.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN tempstamp DATETIME
UPDATE my_table SET tempstamp = STR_TO_DATE(_time, '%Y%m%d%H%i')
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN _time
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE tempstamp _time DATETIME NOT NULL
```

Another approach:  Change the strings in your `_time` to valid datetime values, then alter your column.  If your `varchars()` are wide enough to hold a few extra characters, try this.

```
UPDATE my_table SET `_time`=STR_TO_DATE(`_time`, '%Y%m%d%H%i')
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE `_time` `_time` DATETIME NOT NULL
```

This works because `STR_TO_DATE()` makes `DATETIME` values of your strings, and then MySQL casts them back to strings to store back into your `varchar` column. Then you can change the datatype to `DATETIME`.

You probably noticed I threw in `NOT NULL`.  If you're going to put an index on that column, `NOT NULL` is a good thing to have.  But, if some of your time values are missing, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the database doesn't know what to do with 201409201945, it's not a valid DateTime format, therefore it can't change it

You can delete the data that is in it already, and then try changing it

Comment: this is not answer. comment below question

Comment: deleting the data is not the intent of the OP, I'm sure.

Comment: Then write a peace of code to convert it, he should've specified this.