# Convert String to Datetime Object in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using **MySQL 5.6** and I have datetime stamps like one of this: `2015-01-28 08:30:02:843000`. Currently,  they are stored as strings.  I tried to alter the table to make this into datetime objects but the command failed. I'm rough with SQL, what would be the query to convert these to datetime objects? Do I need to remove the milliseconds somehow? Or convert the last colon to a period?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: well, if it's sql server this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025192/convert-varchar-to-datetime-in-sql-which-is-having-millisec

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to convert varchar to datetime in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948304/unable-to-convert-varchar-to-datetime-in-mysql)

Comment: I'd guess you're reinforcing the general principle that it's a good idea to store the data in its natural format (i.e. a date) let the import and export procedures handle converting to and from the source and usage. It also helps the database manipulate the data more efficiently, in most cases.

Comment: Yea I only have a couple days of data, I'll probably just scrap it and fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
'STR_TO_DATE(str,format)'

Should do the trick for you.  What you want to do 
A) Create New Field (date)
B) UPDATE table set new field convert(old field)
C) You're done